4.1.1 Adding gobo to area light does not work
I am trying to add a noise gobo to an area light as shown in many different tutorials.  However my noise / color ramp do not seem to have any effect not matter how much I adjust.  I've experimented with different values such as a wave and image texture as well as using math to increase/decrease the values going into the color ramp and nothing changes or works.

I found this blender thread that seems to be related but I am not sure if this will help me or how to utilize the info since I have 4.1.1 is sounds like I'd not have that issue.  https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/121174 - I tired the Geometry nodes 'Incoming' socket too and noted that my Area light does not seem to have a 'soft falloff' control.  It almost looks like the gobo might be working with the incoming socket but I cannot adjust the ramp enough to get the desired deep contrast.  This is why I tried to adjust the values with a math node (add and/or multiply/divide)
My basic question is "How can I add a simple ramp adjustable noise gobo to my area light"?  The normal way is not working for me.  Am I missing something obvious?

I downloaded 4.2 and switched from an Area light to a spot light and that seemed to make a difference.  The spot light has the 'soft falloff' control.  I am still hoping for more clarification on this topic

Making a gobo with an area light requires only a few things:

a texture. It could be an image, or procedurally generated. Since it's basically a plane emitting light, the default texture coordinates (UV) already works out of the box.
Light beam spread MUST be zero. Even 2⁰ is enough to make the projected texture significantly blurry.
Use the light's size to control the size/ratio of the projected texture.


Doing any color modification on the texture is done the same way as usual, by adding nodes after the texture node. I.E. to control the color intensity of my texture, I could use a Color Ramp node:

To control the feathering of the texture as it goes to the edge of the light's projection area, this however requires a bit more elbow grease. I like to use the UV input, Separate the X and Y channels, use a Math: Ping-Pong node, a map range to control the offset and the gradient of the feathering, then multiply both channels and multiply the result to the texture:

Which of course can be turned into a nodegroup for easier (re)usage:

